# Lumen 5.5 always getting 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, apache, lumen

When I try to enter [mydomain.com] I see the default version page:

```
Lumen (5.5.2) (Laravel Components 5.5.*)
```

When I try to enter [mydomain.com]/api/user I receive a 404 error.

My web.php looks as follows:

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    // show
    $router->get('user', 'UserController@show');
});
```

What am I missing? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I´m still not 100% sure why this behaviour occured, cause on the same server an additional lumen project worked even before my fix perfectly, but I have found the reason:

The problem depends on an issue with the rewrite engine. It´s quite easy to find out if you have the same problem. If you get a 404 on each route except the `"/"` try out to add `"index.php"` in your URL (e.g.: `domain.com/index.php/user` instead of `domain.com/user`). If now the route can be used you might check your apache config and change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Additionally you can check if your rewirte engine works well by adding the following line to the `.htaccess` inside the `\public` folder of your lumen project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Redirect 301 / https://google.com
  [...]
```

If you´re not redirected to google while requesting any route you need to check your configuration.